How do I see changes to accounting lists (Price Level)? Need to see when/who created an Accounting Lists-Price Level + who/when changed it
How do I audit or see changes to accounting lists (specifically Price Level)?
I need to see when & who created a new Accounting Lists-Price Level as well as who & when it was changed.
Can't find any System Notes, Saved Search or Audit Trail for Accounting Lists
